# How to exclude Table partitions while dumping data using "pg_dump" utility

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way to exclude some partitioned tables while dumping data using `pg_dump.exe` in windows command line.

I have tried following flags of pg_dump to exclude but its not working

`-T schema_name.table.*`

Comment: I put the partitions in a separate echema so that I could exclude them by excluding the schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution. As all my partitions starting with "log_history" .so I have added flag `-T schema_name.log_history*` to exclude them while dumping data.